# Apollo Client useQuery react hook for GET requests

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, react-apollo, graphql-js, react-apollo-hooks

The API resource I am trying to pull from expects a GET request.
How can I use the useQuery hook to send a GET request, it seems like it only ever sends POST requests.

In my limited understanding of GraphQL, should the server be changed so the endpoint for GET_ALL_MODELS is a POST request or do I need to change something on the frontend so my Query sends a GET method request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to implement this.

One is setting up your `ApolloClient` to send all queries as `GET`. This is achieved using [`HttpLink` with `useGETForQueries` as `true`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/advanced-http-networking/#the-httplink-object)

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, HttpLink, ApolloLink } from '@apollo/client';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: '/graphql',
    useGETForQueries: true
  }),
});
```

And in case you need to do it for a specific query, you could [override the `ApolloLink` context](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/advanced-http-networking/#overriding-options) and set `fetchOptions.method` to `GET`.

```
const query = useQuery(gql`...`, {variables: {...}, context: {fetchOptions: {method: 'GET'}}})
```

Comment: really helpful thank you for that, I had looked through the docs so many times and kept finding myself wandering around the useQuery hook documentation,